# How to test if database record is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I've some simple ActiveRecord model let's say:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.for_bucket(bucket)
    create! bucket_id: bucket.id
  end
end
```

Current test is:

```
it 'creates new persistent object' do
    obj = subject.find_for_bucket(bucket)
    expect{ subject.find_for_bucket bucket }.to change{ described_class.count }.by(1)
  end
```

As smart developer I'd like to remove database calls by introducing NullDB to the project.
How can I test method `Order.for_bucket` without touching database ?

Comment: Definitely not touching db in unit tests is desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid hitting the database, I'm afraid you won't be able to expect an actual increase in `described_class.count`. But you can mock the `.create!` method, which is arguably good enough. Actually creating the object after calling `.create!` is something you probably wouldn't need to test since it's already being tested by your chosen ORM, either ActiveRecord or not.

```
it 'creates new persistent object' do
  expect(subject).to receive(:create!).with({ :bucket_id => bucket.id })
  subject.for_bucket(bucket)
end
```